# Do solar flares have a noticeable effect on asteroid orbits?

Tags: asteroids, orbital-mechanics, solar-flare

I've read that in advanced trajectory calculations, sunlight is even taken into account. Does this also apply to transient events like solar flares?

Comment: *Great question!* Mostly unrelated; solar flares heat the atmosphere's of planets and increase atmospheric drag on things passing nearby. This is a big concern for [artificial satellites in Earth orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-flares) but that's not what you're asking about. This effect is going to be really really really small and someone might add an unsourced "No." answer based on that alone, but I suppose once could estimate both the radial force and frictional drag of the increased interplanetary medium and show just how small it is.

Comment: related: [Directionality of solar flares](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44004/7982) and [Strength of the relationship between very large solar flares, coronal mass ejections, and solar proton events?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44716/7982) and [What are the main differences between solar flares and coronal mass ejections?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/87/7982) and [Possible Safe Areas In a Solar Flare](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258074/83380)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: Ha, no.

The solar sunspot cycle (~11 yr) affects a *significant fraction of the photosphere*, to greater and lesser amounts, and it’s a peak-to-valley difference of significantly less than one percent in Watt/m2. You think a flare, which is stochastic in time *and radial vector*, will be relevant? The overwhelming number of flares will be heading in the wrong way, even assuming a 2D Solar System …and the Solar System is 3D.

The Yarkovsky Effect is barely out of the noise for our finest instruments, integrating over *years*. *YEARS*, and only on the favorable asteroid targets. And that’s an effect of sunlight, CONTINUOUS sunlight. At all times, in all vectors. In all 3 dimensions.

And as for the notion of the interplanetary medium somehow increasing, ha, no. That’s a fundamental ignorance of space. Space above, say, 2000 km is a harder vacuum than the hardest vacuum ever drawn by our civilization. Heck, the *coma of comet Churyumov-Gerasimenko* was still *cleaner than a standard cleanroom*. Humans simply do not have a comprehension of just how empty ‘the void’ is, since we live out our lives in the terrestrial existence. It is the burden of a scientist to *un-burden* their mind with such default, Earthly, human assumptions and preconceptions. SPACE IS NOT EARTH, and it’s inhuman, and humans think highly of their own minds.